# Indesign is messing up my text on pdf export. Any ideas on how to rectify?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

When I export my document the text on the exported PDF is changed. It's as if there has been a 'stroke' of the same colour placed around it, so the text looks thick and fuzzy. It's really changing the look of my document and not in a good way, so I need it fixed.
I've tried various export settings, no compression etc. but still the same issues.

Any insight or ideas would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid more information may be needed... a sample screenshot of the bad text, a list of PDF Job Options..etc... "Tried various export settings" is really no information at all.

Comment: Not to mention we don’t know anything about your InDesign document, which may well be where the error lies. Does this happen with all documents or just a specific one? Specifically what type of text does it occur with?

Comment: Have you tested with another font ? Maybe the font is broken. Have you looked at another PDF ? Maybe your Acrobat is broken.

Comment: ok so if I export it as a pdf and open it in photoshop and THEN export it again this clears up the problem. I have no idea why indesign changes it like that. 

I tried several fonts and it happened on all of them

Comment: Photoshop will **rasterize** the entire PDF. Not a wise idea in most instances.